# Why my for loop is changing the behaviour of toggleClass in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a documentation for my website template and I'm trying to create a drop down side menu. The idea is simple: when I click on caret next to the name of the link, its sub-menu should open if I click again, it should be closed. In addition  if any other sub-menus are open, I want them to close, so that only one sub-menu is opened at a time.

**My solution:** I used toggleClass and for loop.

**My problem is:** After I added two for loops to let only one sub-menu be opened at a time, my toggleClass stoped working. Which means when I click on a caret it opens the sub-menu, but clicking on the caret again, it doesn't close the sub-menu and it remains open.

Here is the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $(".indicator").on("click", showLinks);

    function showLinks(){

      var allMenus = $("#ab-menu, #str-menu, #ht-menu");
      var allCarets = $("#ab-caret, #str-caret, #ht-caret");

      for(i = 0; i < allMenus.length; i++){
        $(allMenus).eq(i).removeClass("show");
      }
      for(i = 0; i < allCarets.length; i++){
        $(allCarets).eq(i).removeClass("caret-rotate");
      }

      var linkId = $(this).attr("data-menu");
      var caretId = $(this).attr("data-caret");

      $(linkId).toggleClass("show");
      $(caretId).toggleClass("caret-rotate");

    };

});
```

```css
#ab-menu,
#str-menu,
#ht-menu {
  background-color: #1d3557;
  max-height: 0;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#ab-menu.show,
#str-menu.show,
#ht-menu.show {
  max-height: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fa .fa-caret-down {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
.caret-rotate {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.fa-caret-down.caret-rotate {
  color: #a8dadc;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="about-panel">About <span class="fa fa-caret-down indicator" id="ab-caret" data-menu="#ab-menu" data-caret="#ab-caret"></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu about-sub-menu" id="ab-menu">
          <li class="about-links"><a href="#about">Main Features</a></li>
          <li class="about-links"><a href="#getting-started">Getting Started</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="structure-panel">Structure <span class="fa fa-caret-down indicator" id="str-caret" data-menu="#str-menu" data-caret="#str-caret"></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu structure-sub-menu" id="str-menu">
          <li class="structure-links"><a href="#sections">Sections</a></li>
          <li class="structure-links"><a href="#grid">Bootstrap-grid</a></li>
          <li class="structure-links"><a href="#carousel">Bootstrap Carousel</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="how-to-panel">How-to <span class="fa fa-caret-down indicator" id="ht-caret" data-menu="#ht-menu" data-caret="#ht-caret"></span>
        <ul class="sub-menu how-sub-menu" id="ht-menu">
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#nav">Navigation</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#headers">Headers</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#icons">Icons</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#colors">Colors</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#fonts">Fonts</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="how-to-links"><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="credits"><a href="#credits">Credits</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close; @Goose's edits will work but you also need your other toggleClass() code.  This is working for me:

```
function showLinks(){
    var allMenus = $("#ab-menu, #str-menu, #ht-menu"),
        allCarets = $("#ab-caret, #str-caret, #ht-caret"),
        linkId = $(this).attr("data-menu"),
        caretId = $(this).attr("data-caret");

    $(allMenus).not($(linkId)).removeClass("show");
    $(allCarets).not($(linkId)).removeClass("caret-rotate");

    $(linkId).toggleClass("show");
    $(caretId).toggleClass("caret-rotate");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are right, it works without for loop, but it still doesn't solve the problem that I can't close the opened sub-menu when I click on caret.

Comment: You have almost done it right, I just changed from .not($(linkId)).removeClass("caret-rotate"); to .not($(caretId)).removeClass("caret-rotate");  and it works just as I wanted it to :) Thanks for helping me out guys, much appreciated!

Comment: Oops you're right - I didn't have the carets displaying in my test so didn't notice that bug, sorry.  Glad you worked it out! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The loops are not needed. You can simplify your code like so, I assume this will fix your issue.

```
var allMenus = $("#ab-menu, #str-menu, #ht-menu");
var allCarets = $("#ab-caret, #str-caret, #ht-caret");

allMenus.removeClass("show");
allCarets.removeClass("caret-rotate");
```

Comment: This. Alternatively you could use the `toggleClass` method to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: Tried removing the loops and doing as you showed, but it didn't work.  ToggleClass just opens all sub-menus at the same time. Now the code is totally broken.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get an accurate testing environment without a jsfiddle / grabbing all your dependencies (jQuery and font-awesome from the looks of it), but looking at your DOM I think you might be able to change your on click events to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //Create onclick events for all elements with a class of indicator
    $(".indicator").on("click", function() { 
        //Making jQuery object out of this so we can use jQuery methods
        $this = $(this);
        //Add the caret-rotate class to this
        $this.addClass('caret-rotate');

        //Use the data attribute you made to pass the ID and add a class of show
        $( $this.data("menu") ).addClass("show");

        //The siblings method is very useful here to clear out the caret-rotate classes of everything except this one
        $this.siblings().removeClass("caret-rotate");
        //Grab the siblings again and filter through their children to find the sub-menu class elements, then remove the show class from them
        $this.siblings().children(".sub-menu").removeClass("show");

        //Alternatively you could try this to compress the two lines above into one by chaining the commands, but I can't test right now. Try commenting the above two lines out and uncommenting this when you are testing:
        //$this.siblings().removeClass("caret-rotate").children(".sub-menu").removeClass("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this code together, but there is  still no success. This code just makes the sub-menus open onclick, but I can't close them back. In addition when one sub-menu is open, another one doesn't get closed.